# Unable to display next and previous weeks correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a next and previous button onto my expenses system and it keeps coming back with the wrong week value in the address bar.

The URL should be for example ?selectWeek=w43 and is coming back as ?selectWeek=1

I have written the following the following code;

```
if(isset($_GET['selectWeek'])){
$week  =       $_GET['selectWeek'];

$prev = $week - 1;
$next = $week + 1;

if ($prev < 1) $prev = 1;
if ($next > 53) $next = 53;

}else{
    $ddate  =       date('y-m-d');
    $date = new DateTime($ddate);
    $week = 'w'.$date->format("W");
}
```

Display code

```
<a class='button' href='?selectWeek=<?=$prev?>'>&lt;</a>
<input class='weekno' type='text' name='selectWeek' value='<?=$week?>'>
<a class='button' href='?selectWeek=<?=$next?>'>&gt;</a>
```

Database

```
id - 1
base_charge - 44.25
week - w08
year - 2023
```

I know it's a simple fix but can't seem to work it out :(

Comment: If `selectWeek` is `w08`, then it's not a number and you can't use math on it.

Comment: Is there anyway that it can be done please?

Answer (score 1):

If `$week` is `w08`, then it's not a number and can't be used in math equations. What you can do is strip off the w and and beginning 0s, to turn it into a number. [ltrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) will do that, and leave the trailing 0s, so `w08` becomes `8`, `w28` becomes `28`, and `w20` becomes `20`.

```
$week = $_GET['selectWeek'];
$num_week = ltrim($week, 'w0');
$prev = $num_week - 1;
$next = $num_week + 1;
```

Comment: Your code uses `trim` not `ltrim` though.

Comment: @MarkusAO Aw, crud. That's what I get for retyping instead of copy/pasting. Fixed

Comment: This is awesome, is there anyway to stop removing the 0 on 01 for example please? Removing the 0 from w0 in the code does not work. Thanks. @aynber

Comment: If you want `01`, then change the ltrim to remove just the `w`. But that will make things a bit tricky as numbers starting with 0 can sometimes be treated as hex. I couldn't remember if it made a difference with numbers below 10.